# My permalinks no longer have the "news" category prefix in the link and it's causing 404 errors for articles published on the web

Tags: permalinks

For example, https://pathguide.com/***news***/5-problems-caused-by-a-messy-warehouse/ is what's on the web, but the permalink for the website is: https://pathguide.com/5-problems-caused-by-a-messy-warehouse/

I don't know how/why the category index got stripped/removed - and I don't know how many other URLs out on the web are affected.

Comment: did you recently change your permalink settings or disable/update a plugin? How did you originally set up those permalinks?

Comment: The `news` version of the URL is working fine for me.